# A render pixel flow error is coming. but my app is working fine in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, exception

In my chat app, i used a keyboard just similar to whatsapp, which included an option to choose emoji.
I made an icon on left-side of the `TextFormField` and i used emoji_picker for selecting emojis after tapping onto that icon. Now, using `FocusNode` and `TextEditingController`, I managed to make my keyboard work just as same as it does in WhatsApp(i.e. whenever you tap on icon, you can select emojis from the space, and when you tap inside `TextFormField,` the keyboard will appear in place of that). Now the problem is, it is showing me an exception that the 23 pixels are overflowed. But the YELLOW/BLACK striped line only appears for a second, and then vanishes and the app works fine.

Note that the exception/overflow appears only when i tap on Icon(the icon for emoji, i mentioned in line 1 of this post) after tapping on `TextFormField`. **THAT MEANS WHEN I FIRST TAP ON `TextFormField`, and then tap on icon for selecting emojis, this exception is shown, except this case, no error is shown**. And then it vanishes, and everything works fine.

Please help me, i am stuck and can't point out the root for my problem.

1. Selecting the textfield area.
   [image: The UI when i tapped on the TextFormField Area]

2)The very little instance on pixel flow (I had to record screen to take an ss from video).

[image: The Yellow/Back Lines]

3)Just after a second.

[image: After Tapping on the icon on left]

The exception/error is -

```
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 23 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///C:/Users/Hp/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_whatsapp/lib/Screens/individual_page.dart:137:24
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#4985a relayoutBoundary=up2 OVERFLOWING
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=411.4, 0.0<=h<=321.4)
...  size: Size(411.4, 321.4)
...  direction: vertical
...  mainAxisAlignment: end
...  mainAxisSize: max
...  crossAxisAlignment: center
...  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
====================================================================================================
```

Here's the code -

```
import 'package:emoji_picker/emoji_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_whatsapp/model/chat_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class IndividualPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final ChatModel chatModel;
  IndividualPage({Key key, this.chatModel}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _IndividualPageState createState() => _IndividualPageState();
}

class _IndividualPageState extends State<IndividualPage> {

  bool show=false;
  FocusNode focusNode=FocusNode();
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    focusNode.addListener(() {
      if(focusNode.hasFocus) {
        setState(() {
          show=false;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[350],
      appBar: AppBar(
        titleSpacing: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.01,
        leadingWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
        leading: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            CircleAvatar(
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                widget.chatModel.isGroup
                    ? "assets/groups.svg"
                    : "assets/person.svg",
                color: Colors.white,
                height: 35.0,
              ),
              radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.04,   
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        title: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(widget.chatModel.name),
                Text(
                  'last seen today at 16:03',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.03,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          Icon(
            Icons.videocam,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.call,
          ),
          PopupMenuButton<String>(onSelected: (value) {
            print(value);
          }, itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return [
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text("View Contact"),
                value: "View Contact",
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text("Media, link, and docs"),
                value: "Media, link, and doc",
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text("Search"),
                value: "Search",
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text("Mute Notifications"),
                value: "Mute Notifications",
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text("Wallpaper"),
                value: "Settings",
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                child: Text("More"),
                value: "Settings",
              ),
            ];
          }),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: WillPopScope(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              ListView(),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.88,
                            child: Card(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.0175, right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.017, bottom:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.013),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(23.0),
                                ),
                                child: TextFormField(
                                  controller: _controller,
                                  focusNode: focusNode,
                                  cursorHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.055,
                                  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                  maxLines: 25,
                                  minLines: 1,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    hintText: "Type a message",
                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0, right: 10.0, top: 5.0),
                                    prefixIcon: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                                      child: IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.emoji_emotions_outlined),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          focusNode.unfocus();
                                          focusNode.canRequestFocus=false;
                                          setState(() {
                                            show=!show;
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    suffixIcon: Row(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                      children: [
                                        Transform.rotate(
                                          angle: 320 * math.pi/180,
                                          child: IconButton(
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.attach_file),
                                            onPressed: (){},
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                                          onPressed: (){},
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ))),
                        Padding(
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF128C7E),
                            radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.058,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.mic,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0, right: 1.0),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    show ? EmojiSelect() : Container(),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          onWillPop: () {
            if(show) {
              setState(() {
                show=false;
              });
            }
            else {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
            return Future.value(false);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget EmojiSelect() {
    return EmojiPicker(
      columns: 7,
      rows: 4,
      onEmojiSelected: (emoji, category) {
        print(emoji);
        setState(() {
          _controller.text = _controller.text+emoji.emoji;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you make the body of your `Scaffold` a scrollable widget like `ListView` or `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: Yo, I forgot to use SingleChildScrollView. By wrapping the container with it, problem is solved. Thanks for your help man.

Comment: consider marking my answer as the right one since it helped you please.